# Google Spreadsheet Function That Sums Numbers In A Column When the Row Contains An EXACT Text

Tags: google-sheets

I've been at this problem for a while now. I am trying to sum numbers under a specific column when the rows equal a certain text and then display that sum on a different sheet. So far I came up with this formula: =IF(EXACT(A2,Table!A2:A)=TRUE,SUM(Table!C2:C)); however the only problem is that is sums everything in column C (which makes sense).

I wish there was a way to do something like the following: SUM(Table!C2:C where EXACT(A2,TABLE!A2:A)=TRUE). I've also tried the SUMIF(), DSUM(), and QUERY() functions to no avail. I must be getting logically tripped up somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: =SUM(FILTER(Table!E4:E, EXACT(Table!A4:A,A4)=TRUE)).

Answer (score -1):

=sum ( FILTER (b1:b10, a1:a10 = "Text" ) )

//  the above formula will help you to take the sum of the values in column B when another column A contain a specific text.

The formula is applicable only in Google Spreadsheets